# Larave mysql removes old records

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, laravel, триггер

Подскаите, хочу установить триггер на таблицу.

```
     BEGIN
              DELETE FROM dashboard_statistics WHERE user_id = new.user_id AND 
     created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY);
                                END
```

Вставке sql запроса.

```
  insert into `dashboard_statistics` (`user_id`, 
  `data_visualizations`, `attribute`, `total`, `updated_at`, 
 `created_at`) values (6, 'matches', 'email', total + 1, '2022- 
 05-31 13:01:04', '2022-05-31 13:01:04')
```

Ошибку которую получаю.

```
 General error: 1442 Can't update table 'dashboard_statistics' in stored  
 function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored  
 function/trigger.
```

Я хочу,чтобы таблица сама очищалась от записей для каждого пользователя старше 90 дней и не следить за ней.

Comment: Вы формулируйте задачу, а не только свою неудачную попытку её решить. Структура таблицы (CREATE TABLE), пример данных (INSERT INTO), подробное описание задачи, запрос, который должен инициировать триггер, требуемое конечное состояние данных с пояснениями, почему именно так. *Подскажите,почему так* Потому что OracleDB - не MySQL.

Comment: @Akina Исправил

Comment: Из 5 пунктов выполнен только один, ну может полтора. Маловато. *Я хочу,чтобы таблица сама очищалась от записей для каждого пользователя старше 90 дней и не следить за ней.* Это делается не триггерами. Для этого существует [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я хочу, чтобы таблица сама очищалась от записей для каждого пользователя старше 90 дней и не следить за ней.

```
CREATE EVENT remove_old_rows_from_dashboard_statistics 
ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2022-01-01'
DO
DELETE 
FROM dashboard_statistics 
WHERE created_at < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 90 DAY;
```

Само собой Event Scheduler надо не забыть включить - `event_scheduler = ON` в файле конфигурации или опцией в командной строке сервиса.

Если надо, чтобы единственная запись не удалялась - добавить в запрос ещё одну копию таблицы с соотв. условием связывания.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно